# Dealing with frames - fixed content of a website

Tags: javascript, frame, frameset

I'm working on my website and the main page (index.html) is composed of two frames: page1.html and page2.html. This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>  
<frameset rows="16%,84%" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0">
  <frame name="page1" target="page2" src="page1.html" scrolling="auto">
  <frame name="page2" src="page2.html" target="_self" scrolling="auto">
<noframes></noframes>
</head>
</html>
```

- The first one works as a fixed content of the page that contains
  multiple links to the rest of the site. It is absolutely important
  that this page remains open every moment.
- The second is the "body", the content area, wich is replaced when any
  of the links are clicked.

So here's my problem: if any page is accessed not from index.html, for example, google, page1.html will not exist, since it only opens through index.html and the site will be missing it's main links.

I'm looking for a code that will check if the page "page1.html" is present and if it's not, open it as a frame.

The closest I've got was this javascript code:

```
<script language="javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    if(self==parent)
        window.location.href = "index.htm"
}
</script>
```

It'll redirect any user who enters a page if not from index.html, to it. But that's still no good. Any clues?

Comment: Don't use framesets. They are way outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read your question, first thing that crossed my mind was to read and act upon `window.frames.length`. Exactly what you have done yourself.

**However**, you could pretty much see a `frameset` and `frame` as deprecated technologies nowadays. Instead, put the links in a HTML5 <nav> or regular <div>, then put the content in a HTML5 <article> or another regular <div>. Next load the content dynamically using vanilla/plain JavaScript or a framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

If you insist on putting the navigation links in a "frame" that never goes away, and you want to load HTML files into a sub part of the screen, then I'd still put the navigation links in a <nav> or <div> and use an <iframe> for the content.

Comment: Ok, i'll give it a shot. But how should I deal with the problem I described? If a user enters any page of the website without first going to the index? How would I mantain the frames?

Comment: That is precisely one problem you won't get if you get rid of the frames =)

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand completely. You're saying I should get rid of the frames. Done.
Also that I should put the navigation links in a <nav> or <div> in the main page and use <iframe> for the content that will be replaced. So the index will have only one <iframe>, right?

Comment: Yes, if you insist on putting your contents in a separate HTML file. Thing is that when you have all of your contents on one single web server and all the documents has the same origin, then there's really no need for you to use frames. Think about the user experience (UX). How many sites out there have you seen that put the navigation pane fixed, always floating on top? I'd say a bare minimum. Perhaps none! Such a design steal most valued screen space and remove the page navigation authority from the user. Template the navigation and duplicate him on each page or load content dynamically.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Martin!
And no, I don't care so much for the frames. That's just the solution I found since it's my first try. I'm fresh meat at web development.
I started now learning Jquery and the "dynamical load". That's way more pratical. And I agree with you, the navigation won't be fixed!
**Just one more thing:** I can't see to be able to test the Jquery AJAX(load) while editing. It's supposed to be online, isn't it?

Comment: How cute! DelLeif, it is I who thank you for the pleasure of helping another developer bro' out. If you opened the file locally from the file system and you see something like "file:///" in the start of the URL, then all files loaded thereafter in scripts and through links will be from the local file system too. I'm not sure if the same holds true for the XMLHttpRequest object (Ajax). You should investigate further and perhaps post a new question on stackoverflow! However, installing a web server is really a quick job that pays off =) See [Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org/).

Comment: Indeed! I found out about WAMP little before your reply. Now I have new problems to solve using the Jquery dynamic load. I'll post another question as you suggest. It's too complicated to keep asking here!
Thanks again ;D

Answer (score 0):

Frames are deprecated but anyways:
Check if the page is a parentframe like this:

```
if(window.top == window.self)
```

window.top is the parent frame and window.self is the current frame. It they are equal, there is no parentframe(set).

Comment: Frames is not deprecated. Not even a frameset is. Fact is iframe's are gaining popularity in modern mashup applications. And just a tip, always try to use strict equality operators in JavaScript ("==="), especially so when doing a reference equality test. Often enough, you'll get a performance boost and will increase your code readability.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. Frames are actually obsolete (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#obsolete-elements).

Comment: If you ask me they became obsolete way back =) Thanks for the link!